# Package \newcommand uses @

Tags: packages

I am learning how to write a package by looking at code from existing packages. A nice one on GitHub (https://github.com/amunn/tikz-backgammon/blob/master/tikz-backgammon.sty) uses a lot of  `\newcommand` definitions which contain the @ character (e.g. `\bk@BW` , `\bk@doublestate` etc.). Is this just a style of writing `\newcommand` or does the @ character have special significance?

Comment: Commands normally can't contains @ --- they do in package and style files so that you can have a kind-of private namespace and avoid clashes.

Comment: The `@` is a character that can normally not appear in macro names. It is allowed in macro names in `.sty` files and if it is 'turned on' with `\makeatletter ... \makeatother`. This means that it is often used in 'internal' macros that package users should normally not have to interact with. Using unique prefixes (like `bk`) together with `@` can avoid name clashes. You can read more at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/35864.

Comment: It's only a sort of "protection" by using special characters with a catcode switch. As long as the character has letter catcode in its current usage, you could use whatever you want. LaTeX traditionally uses `@`, `expl3` uses `_` and `:`; ConTeXt uses `_`, `!` and `?` among others as reserved characters...

Comment: Great replies. It's all clear now, thanks guys.